# jqGrid - How to edit and save multiple rows at once?

Tags: jqgrid, editing

We are aware of how to allow users to edit multiple jqGrid rows - but how would one have a single save button that saved all edited rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do it manually (not with a jqGrid feature).

We have a custom formatter which draws editors and we put a `<form>` tag around the whole grid, with a submit button at the bottom.

Comment: So you reload the whole page and grid for a form submission?  Did you try doing it using AJAX?

Comment: No, we don't reload. We submit the form with AJAX, as you guessed.

Comment: Any way you could post a code snippet to get the feel of how you accomplished this?  (We're new to AJAX and jqGrid)

Comment: We use Malsup's ajaxForm plug-in for jQuery. Works fine and there are examples on the site.

Comment: @CraigStuntz, Can you let me know how do you do a custom format for select box in the grid, which loads its options from server w.r.t. above mentioned scenario. I'm kind of stuck here...!      `{name:'code', width:150, editable:true, edittype:"select", editoptions: { name:'code'+'['+'item_id'+']', dataUrl: '/lists/code_list/',  buildSelect: function (data) {
            return "<select ><option val='0'></option>" + data + "</select>"; 
        }}},`                                                 This is what I tried till now. When I click save button this element won't come in the ajax post.

Comment: @Sai: Post this as a new question with more details.

Comment: @CraigStuntz , Please find it here[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091417/formatting-select-boxes-while-doing-a-multiple-row-saving-in-jqgrid