# jqGrid: How to save order data with order detail row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Page contains order header data in form and order details in jqGrid.

Detail can created or changed using inline edit, edit or add form.

If new detail is created and saved  but order header is not saved yet, db exception occurs.

How to save order header before or together with saving detail rows.
There may be two possibilities:

1. Force jqGrid to submit order form by calling SaveDocument() before adding detail line.
   or
2. Send order data together with order row to Add controller.

Any idea how to implement this ?

```
<script>
var grid = $("#grid");
grid.jqGrid({
url: 'GetData',
datatype: "json",
mtype: 'POST',
scroll: 1,
multiselect: true,
            multiboxonly: true,
            scrollingRows : true,
            autoencode: true,
            prmNames:  {id:"_rowid", oper: "_oper" }, 
            colModel: <%= Model.ColModel() %>,
            gridview: true,
            toppager: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            editurl: 'Edit',
            rownumbers: true,
            ondblClickRow:  function(rowId) { beginEdit(rowId) },
});


function SaveDocument()  {
 // Returns false if order detail adding should be cancelled
 var res;
$.ajax({ type: "POST",        
  async: false,
  url: 'AddOrder',
  data : $("#Form").serializeArray(),
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
      alert('Order save is cancelled, correct and try again'); res=false; 
      }
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { res= true; }
  });
 return res;
 }
</script>

<form id="Form" onsubmit='SaveDocument(); return false;'>
Order Date <input name='orderdate'>
Order number <input name='ordernumber'>
<input type='submit' value='Save' />
</form>
<div id="grid1container" style="width: 100%">
    <table id="grid">
    </table>
</div>
```